# Android - Why ImageView is empty?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview

I'm trying to take a photo and show it in ImageView. If i try to fill ImageView from gallery, it works perfectly but if i take a photo using camera, it doesn't work.

Here is what i'm doing:

//choose take from camera or gallery

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment    
.....
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle("Escolha a Foto");
builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) { // pick from
                                                                // camera
            if (item == 0) {

                Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);//zero can be replced with any action code
            } else {
                // pick from file
                Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                           android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);//one can be replced with any action code
            }
        }
    });
....
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 0:
        if (resultCode == -1) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }

        break;
    case 1:
        if (resultCode == -1) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }
        break;
    }
}

private void captureImageInitialization() {

    final String[] items = new String[] { "New Photo",
            "Choose from Gallery" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle("Choose Photo");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (item == 0) {
                Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);//zero can be replced with any action code
            } else {

                Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                           android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);//one can be replced with any action code
            }
        }
    });

    dialog = builder.create();
}
```

Any idea in what's wrong?

UPDATE: The method "onCreateView()" from the fragment is called after save the photo...this is why ImageView is empty...how can i fix it?

UPDATE2: onCreate() from mainActivity is called all time that i use camera.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please show whole code like adapter... ?

Comment: That switch statement makes no sense. You check the value in the switch, and again in your case whether it's `-1`

Comment: ops..the value -1 is about resultcode from 'onActivityResult' and 0 = take from camera, 1 = choose from gallery

Comment: @Haresh i've inserted the code that fill ArrayAdapter

Comment: what is `resultCode == -1` supposed to mean ? isn't there a constant defined for the result codes ?

Comment: I've changed it..    resultCode == -1   is     resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK

Comment: The method "onCreateView()" is called after save the photo..this is why ImageView is empty...how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Always use `intent.getExtras().get("data")` you need to type cast to `Bitmap` for capturing image from Camera.

```
case 0:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bitmapImage = (Bitmap) imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);

        }

        break;
    case 1:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Same problem. Still empty and only works if i choose from gallery!

Comment: @DavidL. have you added these permission? <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" /> and  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Comment: yes!! The problem is that after save photo, it calls 'onCreateView' again inside the fragment that have photo function :( ... how can i avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

also have in mind that there's a bug (mostly noticed on Samsung devices, I don't have current information whether it was fixed or not) where `getData()` returns null. Is that the case, you'll need to use an pre-inserted Uri as following:

```
preinsertedUri = getContentResolver().insert(        
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
```

later in `onActivityResult()` method:

```
Uri imageUri = preinsertedUri;
```

This way I was able to prevent the `Uri` from being null on some Samsung devices

Comment: The URI is not empty...when i took a photo, the object 'URI selectImaged' has the value "content://media/external/images/media/57" but when return to activy, the ImageView is empty...it look likes that i took the photo and the photo is not saved :(